# How to i execute bash commands on jenkins-slave (windows)?

Tags: windows, github, jenkins, jenkins-agent

I am checking out the codes from git-hub repo on windows machine.

```
Steps as follows:
1) launch the git-bash.exe
2) In bash mode, git clone location.
```

This windows machine will be as jenkins-slave.
I need to run these commands on slave machine.
I cannot run these commands as "Execute as windows batch command"

Comment: Can you provide the question in bit clearer,you need to execute the commands in windows slave, what error are you facing?

Comment: 1) open git-bash.exe 2) On bash prompt, cd c:\some_directory 3) git clone commands. These commands to be executed on Windows slave machine. How can I do it ? I can't use "Execute as windows batch command"

Comment: you can write script for bat that contains your requirement and run that in the command prompt.

Comment: @ChandraSekhar : I tried that it didn't work. I could open bash.exe , but next how do you execute commands on bash.exe prompt ?

Comment: Could you help me with batch script for below commands: 1) Open C:\Program Files\git-bash.exe (Next all actions to be performed on git-bash.exe) 2) cd C:\some_directory 3)eval ssh-agent && ssh-add C:\id_rsa 4)git clone "repo"

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is:

1. Add a "Execute windows batch command" step in your Jenkins job's build step.
2. There `cd` to the `bin` folder (ex: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin`) in the git installation directory of your slave system.
3. Then execute your `git clone` command or any other `git`commands you wish to execute.